# Get Company to show suggestions for Yasnippet names

Tags: completion, company-mode, yasnippet

I use the packages Company mode and Yasnippet.  When I'm typing in a buffer, I get autocompletion suggestions from Company.

For Yasnippet, I have a directory which contains the snippets. In that directory I have for example, the file `foo.yasnippet`.

When I'm typing `foo` in the buffer, and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, I get a popup menu for yasnippets, which I chan choose which snippet (`foo` or `foo-bar`) I want to insert. 
I would like to integrate the yasnippet `foo` in Company completion. When I type `foo`, then I would like to see the snippet in Company completion popup.

Is this possible? If so, how could I achieve this? 
In Vim you have that with Neocomplete and VimSnippets. When I googled around, I found [this link with Elisp](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/blob/master/company-yasnippet.el) but I couldn't wrap my head around how to apply it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That elisp is a yasnippet "backend" for company (included with company). You can read about it by typing `C-h f company-yasnippet RET`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I have the following snippet in my configuration and it seems like it's exactly what you want:

```
;; Add yasnippet support for all company backends
;; https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/pull/179
(defvar company-mode/enable-yas t
  "Enable yasnippet for all backends.")

(defun company-mode/backend-with-yas (backend)
  (if (or (not company-mode/enable-yas) (and (listp backend) (member 'company-yasnippet backend)))
      backend
    (append (if (consp backend) backend (list backend))
            '(:with company-yasnippet))))

(setq company-backends (mapcar #'company-mode/backend-with-yas company-backends))
```

Basically it sets up the yasnippet backend with every other backend you have activated, so you get the proper completion for the corresponding backend as well as your snippets.

Comment: I didn't expected to get any answer on this, so Patrick, I'm really grateful for this. Thanks for that!