# Company doesn't load with Yasnippet

Tags: company-mode, yasnippet, eglot

Facing strange problem with auto-completion company-mode.
I use the packages Company mode and Yasnippet. When I'm typing in a buffer, I get autocompletion suggestions from Company with Yasnipper.

But for some reason it stop showing any Yasnippet *snippets* with company suggestion. And taking much longer time to load than before!

*Before my company suggestion was like this :*
[image]

*And after changed to this!?*
[image]

Here is my settings for `company-mode` and `yasnippet`:

```lisp
(use-package company-box
  :delight
  :after company
  :hook (company-mode . company-box-mode))

(use-package company
  :defer 2
  :commands company-mode
  :hook (after-init . global-company-mode)
  :custom
  (company-dabbrev-ignore-case t)
  (company-etags-ignore-case t)
  (company-idle-delay 0.0)
  (company-echo-delay 0)
  (completion-ignore-case t)
  (company-require-match nil)
  (company-show-quick-access t)
  (company-selection-wrap-around t)
  (company-minimum-prefix-length 1)
  (company-dabbrev-code-modes t)
  :config
  ;; Add yasnippet support for all company backends
  ;; https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/pull/179
  (defvar company-mode/enable-yas t "Enable yasnippet for all backends.")
  (defun company-mode/backend-with-yas (backend)
    (if (or (not company-mode/enable-yas) (and (listp backend)    (member 'company-yasnippet backend)))
        backend
      (append (if (consp backend) backend (list backend))
              '(:with company-yasnippet))))
  (setq company-backends (mapcar #'company-mode/backend-with-yas company-backends))

  (setq company-backends '((company-capf :with company-yasnippet)))
  )

(use-package yasnippet
  :delight yas-minor-mode " ¥"
  :commands yas-reload-all
  ;; :hook ((prog-mode minibuffer-inactive-mode org-mode) . yas-minor-mode)
  :bind
  (("C-c y n" . yas-new-snippet)
   ("C-c y v" . yas-visit-snippet-file)
   ("C-c y i" . yas-insert-snippet))
  :custom (yas-snippet-dirs '("~/.emacs.d/etc/yasnippet/snippets"))
  :config
  ;; enalbe nested snippet expansion
  (setq yas-triggers-in-field t)
  (yas-global-mode)
  )

(use-package yasnippet-snippets
  :delight
  :after yas
  :custom (yasnippet-snippets-dirs '("~/.emacs.d/etc/yasnippet/snippets"))
  :config (yasnippet-snippets-initialize))
```

Also I've try this [solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10431/get-company-to-show-suggestions-for-yasnippet-names) but the result is still same!

Another thing which I'd like to say, that I configure a way working this with `eglot`:

```lisp
(use-package eglot
  :config
  (add-to-list 'eglot-server-programs '(c-mode . ("clangd")))
  (add-to-list 'eglot-server-programs '(c++-mode . ("clangd")))
  (add-to-list 'eglot-server-programs '(python-mode . ("pyls")))
  (add-to-list 'eglot-server-programs '(LaTeX-mode . ("digestif")))
  (add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'eglot-ensure)
  (add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'eglot-ensure)
  (add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'eglot-ensure)
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'eglot-ensure)
  ;; format on save
  (add-hook 'c-mode-hook '(lambda() (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'eglot-format-buffer nil t)))
  (add-hook 'c++-mode-hook '(lambda() (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'eglot-format-buffer nil t)))
  (add-hook 'python-mode-hook '(lambda() (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'eglot-format-buffer nil t)))
  (define-key eglot-mode-map (kbd "C-c R") 'eglot-rename)
  (define-key eglot-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-i") 'eglot-find-implementation))

(add-hook 'eglot-managed-mode-hook (lambda ()
                                     (add-to-list 'company-backends
                                                  '(company-capf :with company-yasnippet))))
```

But it does work only with those mode which I `add-hook` within `eglot`.

So basically my question is, **Is there a way to load Yasnippet with company globally**?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to a *solution* for this, I don't know if it's the best or not! Setting `company-backends` doesn't work so, I `add-hook` specific mode `prog-mode`, `org-mode` like this and that's giving me Yasnippet in the `company-backend`.

```lisp
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set (make-local-variable 'company-backends)
                 '((company-files        ; files & directory
                    company-keywords     ; keywords
                    company-capf
                    company-cmake
                    company-yasnippet
                    company-c-headers
                    company-clang        
                    company-irony-c-headers
                    company-irony
                    company-dabbrev-code
                    company-semantic
                    company-gtags
                    company-etags
                    company-rtags
                    company-elisp)))))
```